# How do I generate a UUID in SAP UI5 code?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, uuid

I know how to do that in node.js, with npm-managed libraries like `uuid`. But what's a decent way to do this in browser-based SAP UI5 JavaScript code?

Comment: FYI: `globalThis.crypto.randomUUID()` is now available in all major browsers. Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Generating UUID in plain JavaScript

```js
const myUniversallyUniqueID = globalThis.crypto.randomUUID();
console.log(myUniversallyUniqueID); // e.g.: "a38aa6d5-bf7e-4caa-afe1-0144507e215c"
```

[`crypto.randomUUID`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID) is now supported by all major JS engines. I.e. `globalThis.crypto.randomUUID()` can be used in browsers as well as in Deno / Node.js.

### Generating UID in SAPUI5

Not a UUID, but UI5 provides the function module [`sap/base/util/uid`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/module:sap/base/util/uid) which returns a string that is unique within the same JavaScript context (I.e. it is very possible to generate the exact same UIDs when two iframes run `uid()` at the same time).

```js
const myUniqueID = uid(); // uid required from "sap/base/util/uid"
console.log(myUniqueID); // e.g.: "id-1650235945092-39"
```

The [implementation](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/base/util/uid.js) is fairly simple and easy to understand.